# Accessibly Issues in kendo DropDownList on Angular

Tags: kendo-ui, accessibility, wave, kendo-dropdown, kendo-angular-ui

I am facing an accessibility issue (label error) on [Kendo DropDownList in angular](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/), while testing using the WAVE tool. I am getting the below alert messages on all the kendo dopdownlist.

[image: Accessibility error on kendo dropdownlist]

Message: Orphaned form label. A form label is present, but it is not correctly associated with a form control.

```
            <kendo-formfield>
            <kendo-floatinglabel text="State" >
              <kendo-dropdownlist 
              [disabled]="true"
              [fillMode]="formUiStyle.dropDownFillMode"
              [data]="ddlStates$ | async"
              formControlName="state"              
              textField="stateName"
              valueField="stateCode"
              [valuePrimitive]="true"
              (valueChange)="onStateChange($event)"
              (blur)="validateHomeAddress()"  placeholder="State"
                >
              </kendo-dropdownlist>
            </kendo-floatinglabel>
            <kendo-formerror *ngIf="homeAddress?.state?.errors?.required">
              State is required
            </kendo-formerror>
          </kendo-formfield>
```

[image: html code for kendo dropdownlist]

Facing this issue only for kendo dropdownlist. All other kendo UI controls are working fine. I just want to know how to resolve the accessibility issue which I am facing on the Kendo DropDownList.

Comment: Sorry but there is no question here. Can you please clarify how you would like to be helped?

Comment: I just want to know how to resolve the accessibility issue which I am facing on the Kendo DropDownList. 

Thanks

Comment: What version of the Kendo DropDownList component are you using?

Comment: [According to this FAQ, an orphaned label is a label not associated with a field](https://accessibleweb.com/question-answer/orphaned-form-label/). But the DOM in the screenshot shows that the generated `<label>` _is_ correctly associated with the form control via `for` and `id` attributes, and that the latter has `role=combobox`. Maybe it’s a bug in WAVE due to the label coming _after_ the control? Which is totally valid, btw. Have you tried with a normal `kendo-label`? How would a floating label for a combobox even look like?

Comment: The version I am using is @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^7.0.3"

Comment: I have tried kendo-label as well, `id`, `for`, and  `aria-labelledby` are the same. but still, I am facing the same issue.